# Adding class to error-span using unobtrusive validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm trying to get the example shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtglenn/VwPaR/) to work within my project.

My code currently looks like:

```
<!-- jQuery.validate -->
@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jQueryVal")

<script type="text/javascript">
    TypeScript.Framework.Helper.GlobalHelper.initClientValidation();
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/Bundles/jQueryValUnobtrusive")
```

The two bundles are for `jquery.validation.js` and `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js` as I've already know, that I have to include `validation`, make my changes, and then include `unobtrusive`.

Here the TypeScript:

```
const defaultOptions = {
    errorClass: "help-block",
    highlight(element) {
        const idAttr = `#${$(element).attr("id")}Feedback`;
        $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-success").addClass("has-error");
        $(idAttr).removeClass("glyphicon-ok").addClass("glyphicon-remove");         
    },
    unhighlight(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        const idAttr = `#${$(element).attr("id")}Feedback`;
        $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error").addClass("has-success");
        $(idAttr).removeClass("glyphicon-remove").addClass("glyphicon-ok");         
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement(error, element) {
        if (element.length) {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
};

$.validator.setDefaults(defaultOptions);
```

My login-view has two simple inputs for username and password:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Request.Username, new {@class = "sr-only"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Request.Username, new {@class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Request.Username)
```

However, the `help-block` class never gets assigned to the `span`.
On error it renders to:

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Request.Username" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span id="Request_Username-error" class="">The Username field is required.</span>
</span>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Wondering what's the point of your `errorPlacement` option and the conditional contained within.  Both conditions result in `error.insertAfter(element)`, which is also identical to the default.

Comment: That's only `copy & paste`d and not written by myself

Comment: Isn't is obvious that there is no difference between `error.insertAfter(element)` and `error.insertAfter(element)`?  `error.insertAfter(element)` is also the default code within the plugin.